# In Scala, should it be possible to instantiate an existential type?

Tags: scala

**Updated** to remove bogus example.

Should this (which compiles) be valid?

```
trait Foo[X]
val foos: Seq[Foo[_]] = Seq()
```

These instantiated existentials seem to only lead to a downstream compiler errors, IMHO should not compile, and should instead be written as:

```
val foos: Seq[Foo[Any]] = ...
```

What am I missing?

(A reaction to [this blog post](http://scabl.blogspot.com/2015/01/introduce-type-param-pattern.html).)

Comment: I haven't read the blog post and I'm not saying it's a good idea, but there are plenty of things you can safely do with a `Seq[Foo[_]]` (like taking the length, etc.). What kinds of compiler errors are you referring to specifically?

Comment: @TravisBrown Good point... The particular error, which lead the author in another direction entirely, was a type mismatch where the compiler tried to match Any against _$1.  The post is a pretty easy read.  It surprises me that an existential can be instantiated - to me part of the essence of something being an existential is that it, in general, can't be, because it's partially unspecified.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't always use `Any` since you might have an invariant collection like `mutable.Set` and you surely don't want to specify that you can add whatever you feel like to that set when what you mean is that you don't care about the type parameter at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't really instantiating an existential type here:

```
trait Foo[X]
val foos: Seq[Foo[_]] = Seq()
```

`Seq()` will return `Nil`, which (in no context) is a `List[Nothing]`, or by extension, `Seq[Nothing]`. And a `Seq[Nothing]` is a `Seq[Foo[_]]` (though this is trivial because `Nothing` is a sub-type of anything).

With a slightly more concrete example:

```
scala> val foos: Seq[Foo[_]] = Seq(new Foo[Int]{})
foos: Seq[Foo[_]] = List($anon$1@327ca223)
```

I'm still not instantiating an existential type. I'm creating a `Seq[Foo[Int]]`, which is also a `Seq[Foo[_]]`. And I certainly can't try to do it directly:

```
scala> new Foo[_]{}
<console>:10: error: class type required but Foo[_] found
              new Foo[_]{}
```

`Seq[Foo[_]]` isn't necessarily unsafe. As @TravisBrown suggests, you can still use collection methods that don't depend on the type at all. Even without the type, we can still do (somewhat) useful things with type constraints:

```
def foo(list: List[ _ <: AnyVal]): String = list.mkString

scala> foo(List(1, false, true, 2.3))
res34: String = 1falsetrue2.3
```

Okay, that's not really any more useful that having a `List[AnyVal]` in this case, it's just a little harder to come up with a good use case without a complicated example.

Comment: Thanks.  But my point is that "`_`" isn't a type - it's a placeholder for one in some contexts.  So saying e.g. "`Seq[Foo[Int]]` is a `Seq[Foo[_]]`" should be meaningless.  It would make sense to say `Seq[Foo[Int]]` _matches_ `Seq[Foo[_]]`, but not that it _is_ one.

Comment: `Seq[Foo[_]]` isn't meaningless though. It's a sequence of `Foo` where we *don't care* what the inner type is. Or in the case that it has bounds imposed, we don't care what it is, so long as it obeys our constraints. `_` isn't just a placeholder for one type, either. It's a placeholder for any number of types. In any case, this sounds more like a rant against semantics.

Comment: Sorry, I said it very poorly, and more importantly, I didn't think about your answer hard enough.